# Dynamic argument pasing in corba

Tags: dynamic, arguments, corba

I'm new in building corba application. Presently I'm developping a corba application in java. The problem I have is that I should write a method that receive the name of the class, the method and the arguments to pass to the corba server as a string.
Before invoking the remote method, I have to parse the string and obtain all the necessary information (class, method, arguments)
There is no problem here. But now concerning the arguments i do not now in advance the type of the arguments, so I should be able to convert an argument by getting its type and insert it into a Any bject to be sent, is it possible?
If Know in advance the type such as seq.insert_string("bum") it works but I want to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DynAny interfaces, if your ORB supports them. They can do exactly what you want. From [CORBA Explained Simply](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/meta-information-programming.html#toc74):

> If an application wants to manipulate data embedded inside an `any`
>   without being compiled with the relevant stub code then the
>   application must convert the `any` into a `DynAny`. There are sub-types
>   of DynAny for each IDL construct. For example, there are types called
>   DynStruct, DynUnion, DynSequence and so on.
>
> The operations on the DynAny interfaces allow a programmer to
>   **recursively drill down into a compound data-structure** that is
>   contained within the DynAny and, in so doing, decompose the compound
>   type into its individual components that are built-in types.
>   Operations on the DynAny interface can also be used to recursively
>   build up a compound data-structure from built-in types.

Comment: Dear Brian,Thank you for your helpful information. However, I have been trying to use it that way, but I always get a "Not implemented exception" do you know what can be the cause, I heard that the new JDK doesn't support it. Is there another kind of corba API that i can use that will support it?

Comment: Sounds like the ORB you're using doesn't support it. Try JacORB (http://www.jacorb.org/) or Orbacus (http://www.progress.com/en/orbacus/downloads.html) instead.